# Unable to concatenate two strings

Tags: c, string, function, string-concatenation

I was practicing on the topics of string. I am trying to concatenate two strings without using the `strcat()` function available in C.

This is the code that I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int string_length();
void concatenate();

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello there";
    char str2[] = "How are you";
    char result[100];
    int length;

    length = string_length(str);

    printf("%d\n", length);
    concatenate(result, str, str2);
}

//Function which counts the number of characters of the string
int string_length(char str[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

//Function to concatenate the two strings
void concatenate(char result[], char str[], char str2[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        result[i] = str[i];
        ++i;
    }
    int j = i + 2, k = 0;
    while (str2[k] != '\0') {
        result[j] = str2[k];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", result);
}
```

When I ran this code, this is what I get as the output -

```
    11
    Hello there
```

The concatenation function is not working properly as output should be-

```
    11
    Hello there How are you
```

I used the debugger and found that loops are working fine and as per the counter variable, The two strings should get concatenated.

Comment: Why `j = i + 2;`?

Comment: There's no need for the variable `j`, you could continue to use `i` i the second loop.

Comment: @pmg since the first string will take 11 characters, second string has to start after that, so j = 11+2 = 13. so the seond string will start from index of 13 and will not override the previous string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok that worked! But what was wrong with taking j ?

Comment: So you want to add a space between the strings? Then think about what index that should be added at. And do you really add that space into the `result` string?

Comment: It doesn't work with `j = i + 2` because then you skip two elements of the `result` array. There's two elements whose contents will be *indeterminate*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Since those two elements are indeterminate, ```j = i+2``` will cause the entire loop to not run ?

Comment: Try to rewrite `concatenate` using only 2 index variables... Beginners always try to add more variables to solve problems... You only need two. (and an experienced programmer would do it using only the variables that are the function's parameters.)

Comment: PS: Concatenation would, ordinarily, not insert a space when concatenating... That is something other than concatenation...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I will rewrite the code with 2 variables only, and How can I insert a space between the concatenated strings ?

Comment: You could "magically" insert a space down in the bowels of the function (`result[i++] = ' ';)` OR you could just add a space to the end of the first string. There's already a space between "Hello" and "there"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in your concatenation function, you initialize `j` to `i + 2`, whereas you should just use `j = i` as the first character of the second string should come just after the last character of the first and `i` was incremented after each character copied from `str`. Note that you can just use `i`, there is no need for `j`.
- you must set the null terminator at the end of `result`. You can set at with `result[j] = '\0';`
- you should output the concatenated string in `main` instead of `concatenate()`.
- the prototypes of `string_length()` and `concatenate()` should include the argument types.

Also note that you should use `size_t` for the index types.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t string_length(const char *s);
void concatenate(char *result, const char *str, const char *str2);

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Hello there";
    char str2[] = "How are you";
    char result[100];
    size_t length;

    length = string_length(str);

    printf("%zu\n", length);
    concatenate(result, str, str2);
    printf("%s\n", result);  // shows Hello thereHow are you
    concatenate(result, "abc", "def");
    printf("%s\n", result);  // shows abcdef
    return 0;
}

//Function which counts the number of characters of the string
size_t string_length(const char *s) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

//Function to concatenate the two strings
void concatenate(char *result, const char *str, const char *str2) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0') {
        result[i] = str[i];
        ++i;
    }
    size_t k = 0;
    while (str2[k] != '\0') {
        result[i] = str2[k];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
}
```

Here is an alternative approach, using pointer arithmetics:

```
//Function to concatenate the two strings
void concatenate(char *result, const char *str, const char *str2) {
    // copy the bytes from str, including the null terminator
    while ((*result = *str++) != '\0')
        result++;

    // copy the bytes from str2, including the null terminator
    while ((*result = *str2++) != '\0')
        result++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a few doubts here- You said that I have to add the null terminator at the end, doesn't C automatically add the null terminator at the end of string ? Other than this, my first string ended at index 10 of result[] array, so the '\0' is at index 11, when we start with the second string, does that '\0' get overridden by the first characters of the second string ?

Comment: @ParthRajawat: C only adds the null terminator at the end of string literals. There is no need to set the null terminator at offset `11` because the second string will overwrite it immediately, as you correctly assume, but it must be set at offset `22`, which is the final value of `i`.

Comment: I ran the code as per you and ran my code with out adding the '\0', there seems to be no issue in both. The string is ending automatically.

Comment: @ParthRajawat: NO, The string is **not** ending automatically, the byte in memory at the end of the concatenated string just happens to have a value of `0`. This is pure chance, don't rely on it, the behavior is undefined. Try concatenating smaller strings to the same destination afterwards and you will see what happens when you do not set the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in the fact that your result is empty (hence only 0s in it).
When you skip indexes at line 38, you have a null terminator in your string that stops the reading from printf.
You have to add manually a space if you do not want this comportment.
Add a line after your first while `result[i] = ' ';` and you should have your expected result.

However, as it has been said, you do not have to skip 2 spaces with j. Only one suffices.

Comment: Even with one skipping, the null terminator stopped the other string to be displayed, so i had to override '\0' with the first character of the 2nd string at index 11. only yhen the strings got concatenated

Answer (score 1):

Because you skip two elements of the result array, it will look something like this after the second loop:

```
           +---+---+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
Index    : | 0 | 1 | ... | 9 | 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15| ...
Character: | H | e | ... | r | e | ? | ? | H | o | w | ...
           +---+---+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----
```

At index `11` and `12` there will be two unknown characters.

If you want to add a space you need to explicitly add it. And I recommend you keep the same `i` variable as the `result` array index both when adding the space and in the second loop:

```
// Needs to be define here since it's reused later
unsigned i;

// Copy the first string
for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    result[i] = str[i];
}

// The index i will be right after the last character of the first string
// Add the space there
result[i] = ' ';

// Increase i to the first position of the second string
++i;

// Then copy the second string
for (unsigned k = 0; str2[k] != '\0'; ++k, ++i) {
    result[i] = str2[k];
}

// Now add the string null terminator
result[i] = '\0';
```

After this `result[11]` will be a space, and directly following it (starting at `result[12]`) will be the second string.

Comment: Ok, I am understanding some of this. Can you tell me how exactly are those unknown characters affecting ? I mean, why doesn't the entire concatenated string with with two "?" "?" get printed ? since in integer array unknown indices are replaced with 0.

Comment: @ParthRajawat I only put `?` to exemplify that they are unknown. What they actually are is unknown, it's *indeterminate*. They could be zeros, or they could be anything else. It's better if you look at indeterminate values as *garbage*.

Comment: No no, that is not the point, lol. Leave what the unknown characters are, I want to know why the second string is not getting printed including the garbage values ? Only logical explanation, that I think for this is that the null terminator is automatically getting added at the end of the first string ?

Comment: @ParthRajawat Think about what if one of the unknown characters *is* equal to the null terminator? It's not something that is automatically added.

Comment: ahha, I understand now. Yeah the null terminator is added at the end of strings which are enclosed in a bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Long worded explanations are usually difficult to follow because SO answers are typed (and edited and re-edited), and it is difficult to know what refers to which.

The very first comment response from @pmg tried to draw attention to some strange "index math". You may have imagined that if you 'skipped ahead two' there would magically be an ASCII space there to be printed... Wishes, eh?

Here's a "code dump" that improves on what you have written. By following it, line by line, you may see how it achieves the objective.

```
// notice these (small) functions just get the job done with short variable names
#include <stdio.h> // don't include headers you don't use

// a function DEFINED is a function DECLARED. no prototypes necessary
int string_length( char str[] ) {
    int i = 0;
    while( str[i] ) i++;
    return i;
}

void concatenate( char *dst, char *s1, char *s2 ) {
    while( ( *dst = *s1 ) != '\0') { dst++; s1++; }

    *dst++ = ' '; // padding space inserted

    while( ( *dst++ = *s2++ ) != '\0') { }
}

int main( void ) {
    char str1[] = "Hello there!";
    char str2[] = "How are you?";

    int length = string_length( str1 );
    printf( "'%s' length = %d\n", str1, length );

    char result[100]; // define variables when/where they are used
    concatenate( result, str1, str2 );
    printf( "%s\n", result );

    return 0;
}
```

```
'Hello there!' length = 12
Hello there! How are you?
```

If you're willing to move on from the length function, and start to return useful pointers from your functions, you can have your own versions of two standard library functions (without some of their more advanced features that you'll come to understand in time.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *string_copy( char *dst, char *s ) {
    for( char *p = dst; ( *p++ = *s++ ) != '\0'; ) { }
    return dst;
}

char *string_cat( char *dst, char *s ) {
    char *p = dst;
    while( *p ) p++;
    while( ( *p++ = *s++ ) != '\0') { }
    return dst;
}

int main( void ) {
    char result[100], str1[] = "Hello there!", str2[] = "How are you?";
    
    printf( "%s\n", string_cat( string_cat( string_copy( result, str1 ), " "), str2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected.

```
Hello there! How are you?
```

The reason they are called *functions* is that they take one or more *values*, do something with them, and return something useful. (Think of trigonometry functions like *sin* that takes an angle and returns its y-axis offset on a unit-circle.

The *functions* and *parameters* in the last example have been *nested* to build up to the desired result.)